# What is the algorithm that matlab used in its built-in function 'pca'?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matlab, statistics, approximation

Do anyone know what is the algorithm that MATLAB used in its built-in function "pca"?

I have the following data set:

> 148.9820   55.8438  210.2150
>
> 149.3030   56.8891  208.4280
>
> 151.4400   55.8180  208.9240
>
> 146.5530   55.9677  211.5800
>
> 146.5770   57.2682  209.3680
>
> 145.5330   58.4735  207.6970
>
> 153.9680   55.8386  207.9600
>
> 143.6960   57.2371  211.1020
>
> 152.5960   57.3995  206.2770
>
> 144.1070   56.1439  212.9730
>
> 149.6670   58.8746  205.1560
>
> 142.8440   58.1240  209.7220
>
> 143.2190   59.3990  207.0410
>
> 146.3050   60.2445  204.1980
>
> 156.7100   55.9361  207.4610
>
> 141.0470   57.3240  212.4660

where the number of rows are number of observations and each observation is of dimension 3.

I want to perform principal component analysis on this data set so I wrote

```
 P = pca(A)
```

where A is the above matrix. The answer I got is

```
    0.9480    0.2104    0.2387

   -0.0980   -0.5204    0.8483

   -0.3027    0.8276    0.4727
```

However, when I use the following program:

```
function [evects,evals] = pca_test(dataset)

if (size(dataset,1)>size(dataset,2))

    dataset = dataset';

end

N = size(dataset,2);

mm = mean(dataset,2);

dataset = dataset - mm*ones(1,N);

cc = cov(dataset',1);

[cvv,cdd] = eig(cc);

[~,ii] = sort(diag(cdd));

ii = flip(ii,1);

evects = cvv(:,ii);

cdd = diag(cdd);

evals = cdd(ii);
```

it gives

```
evects = 

-0.9480    0.2104    0.2387
0.0980   -0.5204    0.8483
0.3027    0.8276    0.4727
```

The first column is of opposite sign to the result generated by the built-in pca. Why is there such a change?

I ask this because I think the matlab built-in pca is really slow. The pca_test above is around 3 times faster than the built-in function. But I want it to have exactly the same result as the built-in one. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can read about MATLAB's implementation [on their website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html?searchHighlight=pca). PCA usually involves SVD, and singular vectors are only known up to sign (for real-valued matrices). This means that the choice of sign is arbitrary.

Comment: You can use the command 'edit pca' to open up the pca.m file in Matlab's editor. From there you can look to see exactly how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Principal Components Analysis (PCA) is conducted using a Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) algorithm. As Bill Barth says above, the choice of sign of the principal component vectors is entirely arbitrary.